# Button won't change visibility as intended

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a function that has a multidimentional array that holds n*n numbers, and a vector that holds my programs Buttons.

Right now, my program is able to shuffle the numbers in the array and assign each value to a button, "refreshing the values of each button" everytime I press the button.

I now have a problem when I've tried to hide a specific number (eg.0) each time I "refresh" the button, but it seems it doesn't make the previous button visible when I press the button, which leads to having all the buttons hidden eventually.

This is the code I have right now:

```
    public void Refresh(int NumberToHide)
    {
        foreach (Button b in buttons)
            b.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (buttons[(i * 4 + j)].Content.ToString() == NumberToHide.ToString())
                {
                    buttons[(i * 4 + j)].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                }
                else
                {
                    buttons[(i * 4 + j)].Content = myArray[i, j].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Shouldn't the foreach at the start of the function make every button visible?

Why is it that the buttons that are not visible, don't become visible everytime I call the function?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a note, you could save all those ToString calls and directly assign and compare the Content property with int values.

Comment: how is the `buttons` array declared and filled? use the debugger to step through `Refresh` once to see the true content and states of the buttons.

Comment: I think I see your problem. You don't set the content when you hide a button, but you check if it should be visible based on that content. Maybe setting the content before the visibility check regardless of it's visibility would solve this. (Can't try because a lot of code to reproduce is missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the fact that you **either** hide an element **or** assign a `Content`. Since your visibility check is based on that content, previously invisible elements don't change. I can't reproduce it since a lot of your code is missing, but based on your description I'd check for the **new** content instead of the **current**:

```
public void Refresh(int numberToHide)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            var button = buttons[i * 4 + j];
            button.Content = myArray[i, j];
            button.Visibility = myArray[i, j] == numberToHide ?
                Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh now I realize! Yep when I was hiding my number I wasn't updating it's value, so obviously all buttons will end up hidden. Thanks for the help!